# Can we apply fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, control-theory

Let us assume that $t_0$ and $t_1$ are some constants, and $f(t)$ and $u(t)$ is a continuous mapping from $[t_0,t_1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively. Suppose that
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left[\int_0^t u(\tau)^TB^Te^{A(t-\tau)}C^Td\tau\right].\left[f(t)-\int_0^tCe^{A(t-\tau)}B\hat{u}(\tau)d\tau\right] dt = 0, \text{ for all } u(\tau). $$
Here, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, C\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$.
I want to find the solution to $\hat{u}(t)$, so can we imply anything about $\hat{u}(t)$? I'm thinking whether the result of Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations can be used here, but I'm still new to the topic. Any help will be good.

Comment: More context is needed. Also you say for all $u$,  but for all $u$ in what set/space.

Comment: Also please define all the variables involved in your expressions.

Comment: I made some revision to my problem formulation, so please let me know if it's still confusing

Comment: What do you mean by "all $u(\tau)$"? Do you also allow for Dirac distributions too? In which space $u$ lies? Also are you sure that some transpose symbols are not missing in the left factor? Finally what is the function $f$? Is it given? What properties does it have?

Comment: Also, do you have any property on the system $(A,B,C)$ such as output controllability, stability, etc.

Comment: I believe $u(\tau)$ can be any functions in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Also, $f(t) = -(Ce^{At}x_0)$, where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose we know it.

Comment: Also, you can assume the system properties as you want.

Comment: I have asked two times to clarify what you mean by "all $u(\tau)$". Can you please address that.